# Where can I find a PDF of the documentation for Ubuntu?

Tags: documentation

Is there a FULL PDF manual on the Ubuntu Operating Software that can be printed as oppose to reading on the internet?  I prefer a hard copy.

Answer (score 5):

There is even a special website for this called: http://ubuntu-manual.org/. Here is a [direct link to the PDF](http://files.ubuntu-manual.org/manuals/getting-started-with-ubuntu/12.10/en_US/screen/Getting%20Started%20with%20Ubuntu%2012.10.pdf). Save the PDF or just print it and you are set to go. 143 pages so not to bad.

[If anyone is interested in the server editon PDF click this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf).

Comment: This is what I was looking for tks:-))

Comment: @DavidHuggins dont forget to upvote and accept if applicable ;)